# "Warning message: package ‘ XLConnect ’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)"

Tags: r, package, xlconnect

I receive this message when I try to install "XLConnect" in R. I am trying to use some data from excel, and I don't know how else to load it into the program.

I'm completely new to R and programming, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: OT, but `XLConnect` requires Java, which on macOS in particular will cause significant grief. `openxlsx` is a nice C++ based alternative, or `readxl` if you only need to import. `rio` is an interesting alternative that wraps both plus a lot of other useful I/O packages in a consistent interface.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when there is a typo in the package name. The code below should work. My guess is that the capitalization might have been off when you tried it?

```
install.packages("XLConnect")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably sure that you had spaces on either side of term "XLConnect". At least that is what your error message is telling us. If trying what Mallick suggested does not succeed, then [edit] to include exact copies of any error message in the body of the question.

Other ways to transfer data from Excel to R include copying to the Clipboard or exporting as a '.csv' file. There must be  hundreds of questions and answers about the Excel - to - R Highway Eternal Resurfacing Project. One more recent addition is the `readxl` package (function is `read_excel`) and that choice doesn't have the Java version dependencies that cause trouble for some XLConnect useRs.

Comment: I agree. The readxl package is probably the best way to go for importing Excel data into R.